# How to change JIRA service port number on Windows

Tags: jira, port-number

I have to run an application on a port number (8080), as Jira is already running on that port, Jira is blocking the new application to run on 8080 port.

I have changed Jira's port number in JIRA-> CONF-> Server.xml file (from 8080 to 8100) and saved the file.

Now when I start the new application on http://localhost:8080, the message

> 'Oops, you've found a dead link.'

is shown with Atlassian content in the background of the page.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if JIRA is still running on port 8080. Did you stop and start JIRA after you updated its server.xml?

If you did, you may have updated the wrong attribute in server.xml.

You can find an example of what to update [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/changing-jira-s-tcp-ports-135949.html).

Comment: Thanks Glenn.                                                                                                              I have started and stopped JIRA for few times and finally JIRA stopped running on port 8080.

Comment: Yes, depending on your setup, JIRA often has problems stopping itself and you may have to kill the process manually.